# Openvpn in Azure : how to resolve hosts

Tags: openvpn, azure

I successfully managed to install an OpenVPN machine in my Azure network.

I can connect to it and ping my internal LAN without any issues.

```
~  ping 10.0.0.8
PING 10.0.0.8 (10.0.0.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.0.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=63 time=19.637 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=20.942 ms
```

I would like to use hosts defined in azure to access my machine directl. Here 10.0.0.8 has mymachine1 as hostname. When I try to ping it, i got the following error message:

```
~  ping mymachine1
ping: cannot resolve mymachine1: Unknown host
```

Do you have an idea about what i should do in this case ?

thanks a lot.

**EDIT:**
When using the full hostname it works like a charm.

```
 ~  ping mymachine1.ZZZZZZZZZZZZ.RR.internal.cloudapp.net
PING mymachine1.ZZZZZZZZZZZZ.RR.internal.cloudapp.net (10.0.0.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.0.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=63 time=21.239 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=20.069 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

You need DNS for this; if you have a domain controller in your Azure network, then you already have a DNS server in place; otherwise, you'll need to setup one (be it a full-blown DC or simply a VM running the DNS service); then you'll configure this DNS on your VPN clients and you'll be able to resolve names for Azure VMs.

Failing that, your only option is to use the `hosts` files on your VPN clients.

Comment: I see. I seem to have some DNS there. I edited my question.

Comment: Those are Azure's DNS, which automatically create a public and a private name on-the-fly for each and every Azure VM; but as you have already noticed, they are quite unwieldy. If you need simpler names, you need to run your own DNS.

Comment: I found a workaround. In openvpn config i added a DNS suffix. Now i can ping mymachine1 and it works perfectly :) it will do the job for now.